# Post data JQuery UI Tabs 1.10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework, post

I just switched from *JQ UI 1.8.23 to 1.10.* As for this version, `ajaxOptions` is deprecated and now `ui.ajaxSettings` is used instead.

This is how my code looked like:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            type : 'POST',
            data : 'format=html',
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo. " );
            },
            success: function() { 
                *Something in here*
            }
        }
    });
```

everything worked just fine. Now the new code:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
         beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
             ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'POST';
             ui.ajaxSettings.data = 'format=html';
             ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                 ui.panel.html(
                 "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                 "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                });  
             ui.jqXHR.success(function(){
*something in here*
                });
        }
    });
```

So I need to post this data `format=html` to my server but with the new Version my post variables sent to the server are empty. Nothing is sent to the server. Also, if I want to get the POST-variables in my `php script` the array is empty. I am using `ZEND` btw. I need to send it via POST - there is no way around it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you solve this ? I have searched and there seems to be no resolution. Looks like the UI-Tabs design has an important feature - the ability to add post-data - left out !

Comment: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8673

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source for [jQuery.ajax](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L484-L489), on line 486 you will see it add the data to the url.  Then on line 532 it calls the beforeSend method, which is what triggers the beforeLoad event in jQuery UI tabs.

So all you need to do is modify the url rather than data:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'POST';
        ui.ajaxSettings.url += ( /\?/.test( ui.ajaxSettings.url ) ? "&" : "?" ) + 'format=html';
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
            ui.panel.html(
                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });  
        ui.jqXHR.success(function(){
            *something in here*
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem.
I have tested this :

```
ui.ajaxSettings.url += ( /\?/.test( ui.ajaxSettings.url ) ? "&" : "?" ) + 'format=html';
```

But it's a `GET` type not a `POST`.

I have tried :

```
ui.ajaxSettings.format = 'html';
```

But it wasnt any variable in the post.

So I have tried:

```
 ui.ajaxSettings.data = { format:'html' };
```

No Variable anymore in the post.

Comment: The data will need to be processed prior to the beforeLoad. From the API documentation:

Note: Although ui.ajaxSettings is provided and can be modified, some of these settings have already been processed by jQuery. For example, prefilters have been applied, ***data has been processed, and type has been determined***. The beforeLoad event occurs at the same time, and therefore has the same restrictions, as the beforeSend callback from jQuery.ajax().

Answer (score 1):

Thank you *Christian Seifert* for posting the question and *PetersenDidIt* for the nice answer! Here is my ajax implementation of the same problem, hope this code snippet will help someone out there!

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
            var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/ajax";
            var data = {name: "job", value: "Rock Star"};

            ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'GET';
            ui.ajaxSettings.url = url  + "?" + $.param(data, false);

            //console.log(ui.ajaxSettings.url);
            ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                ui.panel.html('Couldn't load this tab!');
            });
        }
    });
```

Also, pay attention what jqXHR methods you are overwriting, latest Jquery UI (ver. 1.11.4) does not use depreciated methods anymore.

https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui/commit/e3f94a87dc312c2225e9ebe7231d868820bd6150